# Very precise periodic function calls in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp

I am using Python on Windows platform and I need to periodically execute a piece of code every 100ms or lower. For an example:

```
while (packetNumber < 30000):
    sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
    packetNumber = packetNumber + 1
    print("Sent the", packetNumber, "th packet")
```

I only care about calling time of this line:

```
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
```

and it needs to be called every 100ms (or as accurate as possible), in periods like:

11:24:07.00000

11:24:07.10000

11:24:07.20000

11:24:07.30000

etc.

What is the most accurate method of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you. Here you go do_something() is called every 100ms.

This code also proves itself that the method is executed 10 times in a second. i.e. it is executed every 100ms. See the Result.

```
import threading
from time import time

def quit(delta):
    print(delta)
    return int(delta) == 1

def do_something(*args):
    then = args[0]
    now = time()
    if quit(now - then):
        threading.Timer(0.1, do_something, [then, quit]).cancel()
    else:
        threading.Timer(0.1, do_something, [then, quit]).start()

do_something(time())
```

Result:

```
0.10426497459411621
0.2058699131011963
0.3096139430999756
0.4199540615081787
0.525109052658081
0.6257798671722412
0.7308750152587891
0.8337719440460205
0.9371669292449951
1.041382074356079
```

Comment: This does the work but it is very inaccurate, sometimes the time delta is about 80-120ms. Something more accurate is needed.

Comment: I doubt that. I am not sure what you needed. threading.Timer works properly for me.

Comment: @J.Babic Here you go, you got a proof of it being executed every 100ms.

Comment: Switching from Windows OS to Linux due to better timer resoulution fixed my problem and made it very accurate. Sorry for late response and thank you for your effort.

Comment: @J.Babic if the answer worked for you. Do accept the answer and close it.